# how to select the biggest number of a sequential series of number in python in a Poker game

Tags: python

I'm basically trying to identify a straight in a poker game written in python. So if it's 10 high straight I need a function that can eliminate the cards above 10, like a queen.
I've written my code to identify a straight in a series of numbers and it returns a value of True for a straight variable, but I don't know how to identify the biggest number of the straight without knowing that number.
Because if 12 stands for Queen:

playershand = (3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12)

I use sort() to sort the list, but playershand[6] or max(playershand) gives me 12, but I want 10 without knowing where 10 is and without knowing I want 10(because I want the highest number of any possible straight???

Comment: `7, 8, 9, 10, 11` is a higher straight than `6, 7, 8, 9, 10` Who would play the 10-high straight over a queen-high straight?

Comment: Sorry i meant 12 not 11

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you could create a set with the player's hand and find the highest card for which the straight is present in the set (no sorting necessary).

```
playersHand = (3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12)

handSet     = set(playersHand)
maxStraight = max(handSet.issuperset(range(n,n+5))*(n+4) for n in handSet)

print(maxStraight) # 10
```

Comment: thanks but i don't get it handSet.issuperset(range(n,n+5)) returns a boolean value how can you multiply that wouldn't you need an if statement saying if handSet.issuperset(range(n,n+5)) is true than print(handSet[n]+4)? or something

Comment: Python can multiply a boolean with an integer.  False is treated as zero and True is treated as 1.  Which means that cards that don't start a straight will return zero and those that do will return the value of the high card (n+4)

Comment: wow i didn't know that.  A lot simpler than what i wanted  to do. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work for you:

```
hand = [15,3,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
i=-1
hand.sort()
while hand[i] > 10:
    i -= 1
print(hand[i])
```

The negative list index counts from the end of the list so if you have a condition like must be less than 10 you can count backwards until you find what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm well aware of how the game of poker is played, but OP seems to be making their own version.

Comment: what about if 10 is unknown? I mean what if it's 7 high straight. the function must be able to recognize the highest number. Wouldn't you need some sort of loop in a loop?

Comment: I'd say that's a different question all together. What you're asking now is how to find a straight. I'll have to think about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to go that route you would first need to remove any elements above 10 from your list such as:

```
players_hand = [3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
players_hand_reduced = [x for x in players_hand if x <= 10]
```

I agree with the comment, though. A queen-high straight absolutely wins against a 10-high.

Comment: Sorry i wasn't clear enough. I made an edit. It has to be a function for any straight so 10 might be any number that ends a straight of 5 number